# Is it better to have uwsgi installed systemwide or within virtulenv?

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I'm running a Django app with uWSGI, and I launch it using [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/).

Below is the line in upstart's conf file that launch uwsgi.

```
exec /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini path-to-uwsgi.ini
```

**Django is installed in a virtualenv while uWSGI is installed systemwide.** Is it better to also have uWSGI in virtualenv or leave it like this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be better choice to install both on the same environment (at this case the current using virutalenv)
When you activate a virtualenv, at first the commands or imports executed will be run on virtualenv and then through system wide, so with installing both on the same place, what should be done will shorten.
There's a complete tutorial on preparing your desired environment.

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html